# CURRENT_UTC_TIME and timezone issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

I hope you will understand and help me.

My Sql Server is in South Africa(GMT+2)

My Application is in USA (GMT-6)

My Client(mobile) was in South Africa, now in Brazil (GMT-4).

The `LastUpdateTime` of a record in a table was supposed to be 10:25am while the client time was 4:25am. At this time the server indicates 2:25am (or something like that)

I taught I can use the `GETUTCDATE` function in sql for now insertions. But My questions are:

1. How do I convert all old records' `LastUpdateTime` into UTC DATE automatically?
2. is this conversion a good idea or I may do it in the application?
3. How can I allow the config of server timezone in my `web.config` file `appSetting` section (this in order to mention it every time the server timezone changes)?

Comment: Is it not better store as [UNIX timestamp](http://skinn3r.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/t-sql-datetime-to-unix-timestamp/comment-page-1/)

Comment: of course but the default value should be `GETUTCDATE` instead of `GETDATE`. Souldn't it?

Comment: @EmilioGort - sure it can.  Why wouldn't it?  `GETUTCDATE` returns a `datetime` type.  It can certainly be indexed.

Comment: @EmilioGort - I'm not sure what that means, but it's always best to use the environments built-in data types.  A unix timestamp is an integer, not a `datetime`, and it would have to be derived from a function like `GETUTCDATE` anyway.  Also, it's only precise to whole seconds.

Comment: @MattJohnson but with unix timestamp, you get always the right time no matter the timezone, you can forget about that problem, at the end you have to get the date and subtract hours and all that stuff. my thougt

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways that are acceptable to store a value like `LastUpdateTime`:

- In terms of UTC, in a `datetime` or `datetime2` field
- In terms of local time, in a `datetimeoffset` field

If you've stored local time in a `datetime` field, then the value is potentially ambiguous.  Conversion to UTC will require external knowledge of how the original data was captured.

If the values were captured by SQL's `GETDATE` statement, then the time zone of the SQL Server is relevant.  South Africa's time is always UTC+02:00, so you can either:

- Keep the value in the same field and subtract two hours to adjust to UTC
- *or*, copy the value to a `datetimeoffset` field, leaving the orignal value and using a UTC+02:00 offset.

However, if the value was obtained in another time zone, then you would need to know what time zone that was.  You might also run into problems with daylight saving time, as many time zones are not fixed to a single offset.

You said the application was in USA GMT-6, but that doesn't make sense.  Central time in the USA alternates between UTC-06:00 and UTC-05:00, while Mountain Time in the US alternates between UTC-07:00 and UTC-06:00.  You'll need to know which time zone it was, and then you'll have to be prepared for potential overlap due to the [fall-back daylight saving time transition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

With regards to whether to the web.config file - that's more of an ASP.Net question, rather than a SQL Server one.  However, I can tell you now that there's no magic config setting to do this.  Your application must correctly use `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc`, or use `DateTimeOffset`, and you may need to involve `TimeZoneInfo` to do conversions.  It's impossible to offer better advice here, because you haven't shown any code and this is a very broad topic.